# HCP and FCC same?

Tags: spheres, packing-problem

FCC can be created if we keep on putting SCC 2d layers on top of each other's depression is it in some way possible for HCP {3d} too?
More importantly the picture below looks exactly like FCC .My question is FCC and HCP the same thing viewed from different angles?
  [image]